# Error on MySQL Trigger Creation found : 1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

As a database designer ,I need to create a trigger at the table so that I can create the new value at the column `PIB_DTL_CD`  as `PIB0000000001` when the 
value at the column `PIB_DTL_ID` is `1` (auto increment, private key)

I need to create the trigger but I am not where the error is about . Would you please tell me what is the recommend practice ?

I would like to create a mysql trigger to

Here is my SQL Code for the trigger:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER `b_pib_ref_gen`
    BEFORE INSERT ON  `prd_test6`.`b_pib_detail` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF new.PIB_DTL_CD IS NULL
            set @auto_id := (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                             WHERE TABLE_NAME='b_pib_detail' AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() ); 
            set NEW.PIB_DTL_CD =  CONCAT('PIB', LPAD( @auto_id + 1 , 10, '0'))  ;
        ENF IF;
    END;
```

Updates:

Maria DB Version is 10.4.8-MariaDB

Comment: I would not use a trigger at all. Build the string when you select from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using generated columns?

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 22
Server version: 10.1.14-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t
    -> (id int auto_increment primary key, val int,
    -> pb_id varchar(20) as (concat('pb',LPAD(id, 10, '0')))
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t(val) values
    -> (1),(2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+--------------+
| id | val  | pb_id        |
+----+------+--------------+
|  1 |    1 | pb0000000001 |
|  2 |    2 | pb0000000002 |
+----+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```